# Java: How to enable JIT?

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, jit

I have a problem running a Java application through Eclipse. Upon clicking Run, a prompt shows:

"Assertion failed!
Program:../truetype.c
Line: 2133

Expression: glyph != NULL

(Please Retry to debug the application - JIT must be enabled)"

[image]
* Upon clicking Retry, a prompt shows "javaw.exe has stopped working".

[image]

I tried to restart my laptop but the problem still occurs. Anyone knows how to solve it? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT 1 :**
Below is the code I try to run.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    initView();
}

private static void initView() {
    final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setTitle("Testing 101");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    final JTextField nameTextField = new JTextField();
    frame.getContentPane().add(nameTextField);

    JButton saveButton = new JButton();
    saveButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Hello "+nameTextField.getText());
        }
    });
    frame.getContentPane().add(saveButton);

    // Display.
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Which version of the JDK do you have installed? In none of the trees I've looked at is there a `src/share/native/sun/awt/font` directory, nor a `truetype.c` with a `glyph != NULL` assertion in/near line 2133. If it's a really old version, consider upgrading to the latest; the issue may already have been resolved there.

Comment: Hello @ChrisJester-Young , you are right. The previous version I used is 1.3, I've tried using 1.6 and it's now working. Thanks! By the way, your comment is my accepted answer, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I thing your problem is not about "enable JIT", maybe with your java installation

Just-In-Time Debugging - see what JIT is first

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hs4b7a6(v=vs.80).aspx

How to: Enable/Disable Just-In-Time Debugging

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8kf6y2a(v=vs.80).aspx

Troubleshooting

- check you java instation

  - try to run you java program from "command line": java NAME_OF_CLASS_WITH_MAIN
- Check are eclipse instalation

  - try to run other java program from "eclipse"